# how to use UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching if total number of rows is unknown?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to achieve a smooth scrolling experience for `UITableView` so I need to use `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` but there is a problem: the API doesn't send a total number of data. So is there a walk around for this case?

**Update:**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func loadNextBatch() {
        // load next page then append to data
        self.data.append(contentsOf: requests)
    }
```

Comment: Add the code that you've already tried.

Comment: @PGDev my code is inserted

Comment: have you read the docs here? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching.   I think you might find the bottom section about loading data asynchronously helpful

Answer (score -2):

You can use prefetchRowsAtIndexPaths method of the UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching

```
extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            for indexPath in indexPaths {
                if indexPath.row < self.timelineItems.count {
                    if timelineItems[indexPath.row].imageDownloadStatus == .none {
                        timelineItems[indexPath.row].imageDownloadStatus = .downloading
                        ImageService.shared.retrieveImage(for: timelineItems[indexPath.row].imageUrl) { [weak self] (image) in
                            timelineItems[indexPath.row].imageDownloadStatus = .downloaded
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but my question was about implementation of numberOfRowsInSection if not fetched data count is not known

Comment: no need to know total number of data, this method gives you some index paths around your current index, so you can get your data using index path and use it do you want.

Comment: You've misled us by mentioning UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching, as i understand your request is related to the load more process, the prefetch process is not used to fetch the next data from your api, it is often used in situations such as pre downloading pictures or videos of your data.